# Using non-drinkable water for bathing a baby/cleaning baby bottles

Tags: newborn, bottle-feeding, bathing, water

We live in an area where tap water is not recommended for drinking both because of bacteria and chemical pollution. We have been using the water for showering, cleaning and washing the dishes without a significant problem, and use store-bought drinking water for other purposes such as cooking and washing fruits and vegetables. We, unfortunately, do not have the means to have the tap water tested to see what may be in it.

In this situation, would you recommend using the tap water to bath a newborn/baby or to sterilize baby bottles? Any other particular baby-related uses that we should steer away from with the tap water?

Comment: I want you to get an answer, I really do, but this question is likely to attract answers without reliable sources. Is there any reason you haven't discussed this with the child's doctor? If you have, what did they say? They are most likely to be in the best position to answer this question. If you have a specific reason for asking here rather than  taking your doctor's advice, please edit your question and include it. Thanks.

Comment: The baby is not born yet. We are now just investigating how to approach this problem. We tried to look for general medical advice online (i.e., official channels of hospitals and medical practitioners), but haven't seen anyone addressing this specific issue of contaminated water. We are, naturally, intending to consult with the ob-gyn during the next visit, but also think they may not have an advice (they are not familiar with our water situation). That is why we were wondering whether others had a similar dilemma and how they tackled it.

Comment: OB-GYNs are not going to have answers, as they don't do child care. Find out who your baby's pediatrician will be (if you don't know already); they are the one with which to speak. Your problem is fairly localized and even you do not know specifically what is in your water. I doubt we can do better than a local doctor.

Comment: A pediatrician actually may not be the sole source you should inquire about on this. Can you clarify where you are that non-potable water is being sent to your house? For the US, the potability of water delivered to your house is usually regulated by on the state level. If you're on well water, the well driller is typically responsible for certifying the potability of the water being pumped. Can you further clarify what the impediments are to getting the water testing? The specific nature of the contamination will directly affect what needs to be done to render the water potable.